# Do amazon live-testing purchases use real money?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I set up live-testing for my amazon app and i'm able to view the dialog to complete a purchase for an IAP, it doesn't say anything about it being a test purchase, are these purchases going to show up on my credit card?

I want to be careful before testing a bunch of payment scenarios to make sure I'm not racking up a huge bill.

Answer (score 2):

According to Amazon live testing won't charge your testers anything:

> Testers are not charged for downloading your test app, and are not charged for in-app items.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/live-app-testing